# PHP server-side covert xml to json, outcome has different format

Tags: php, json, xml

I'm trying to convert xml to json, i have tried to use the following code,

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($response, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);
$json = json_encode($xml);
$arr = json_decode($json,true);
```

This code is working fine, but there is one problem, 
some of the content in the XML file have chance to have multiple value or only one value, the outcome of the XML conversion of these values will be different, for single value it will be a key associate with a single value, for multi values, it will return an array. My Question is How can i make sure the returning value is consistent.

Here are the example of return value.

multi value

```
"item": [
                    {
                        "product_id": "XL2",
                        "description": "222 For You",
                        "d_image": "D_NUL.png",
                        "m_image": "M_NUL.png",
                        "dm_image": "DM_NUL.png",
                        "whole_toppings": {
                            "topping": "PEPPERONI"
                        },
                        "left_toppings": {
                            "topping": "MUSHROOMS"
                        },
                        "right_toppings": {
                            "topping": "ANCHOVIES"
                        },
                        "crust": "THICK CRUST (REGULAR)",
                        "sauce": "REGULAR",
                        "cook": "REGULAR"
                    },
                    {
                        "product_id": "XLA",
                        "description": [],
                        "d_image": "D_NUL.png",
                        "m_image": "M_NUL.png",
                        "dm_image": "DM_NUL.png",
                        "whole_toppings": {
                            "topping": "PEPPERONI"
                        },
                        "left_toppings": {
                            "topping": "MUSHROOMS"
                        },
                        "right_toppings": {
                            "topping": "ANCHOVIES"
                        },
                        "crust": "THICK CRUST (REGULAR)",
                        "sauce": "REGULAR",
                        "cook": "REGULAR"
                    }
                ]
            },
```

single value:

```
"item": {
                    "product_id": "MMED",
                    "description": "Mediterranean",
                    "d_image": "D_NUL.png",
                    "m_image": "M_NUL.png",
                    "dm_image": "DM_NUL.png",
                    "whole_toppings": {
                        "topping": [
                            "PEPPERONI",
                            "NO ONIONS",
                            "NO FETA CHEESE",
                            "NO SEASONED BEEF",
                            "NO TOMATOES"
                        ]
                    },
```

My expected outcome will be

```
"item": [{
                    "product_id": "MMED",
                    "description": "Mediterranean",
                    "d_image": "D_NUL.png",
                    "m_image": "M_NUL.png",
                    "dm_image": "DM_NUL.png",
                    "whole_toppings": {
                        "topping": [
                            "PEPPERONI",
                            "NO ONIONS",
                            "NO FETA CHEESE",
                            "NO SEASONED BEEF",
                            "NO TOMATOES"
                        ]
                    }],
```

Thanks for helping.

Comment: So you want `"product_id": "XL2"` to be `"product_id": ["XL2"]` instead?

Comment: if item:{ }  only have one single value, instead of just returning one object , i want the returning value to be a Array contain one object. Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand, could you provide an example of the expected output in your question?

Comment: "item":[ {
                    "product_id": "MMED",
                    "description": "Mediterranean",
                    "d_image": "D_NUL.png",
                    "m_image": "M_NUL.png",
                    "dm_image": "DM_NUL.png",
                    "whole_toppings": {
                        "topping": [
                            "PEPPERONI",
                            "NO ONIONS",
                            "NO FETA CHEESE",
                            "NO SEASONED BEEF",
                            "NO TOMATOES"
                        ]
                    }],

Comment: I cannot read that at all. Edit that information into your question.

Comment: i have edited the question, please see above

Comment: json_encode will generally just encode exactly what it's given. So I'd assume that the structure of `$xml` is the problem. Maybe show us that object (using var_dump() or print_r) - or at least the "item" part of it

Answer (score 0):

You're relying on the automatic object serialization of SimpleXML. Here is no information available that a XML element MIGHT have siblings with the same name. The information is not there so no automatic conversion can create the output you want. (Not without something providing that information.)

You will need to traverse the XML tree and generate your specific output. Here is an reduced example:

```
$xml = <<<'XML'
<items>
  <item>
    <product_id>1</product_id>
    <whole_toppings>
      <topping>PEPPERONI</topping>
    </whole_toppings>
  </item>
  <item>
    <product_id>2</product_id>
    <whole_toppings>
      <topping>PEPPERONI</topping>
      <topping>MUSHROOMS</topping>
    </whole_toppings>
  </item>
</items>
XML;

$itemsElement = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);

$items = [];
foreach ($itemsElement->item as $itemElement) {
  $item = [
    'product_id' => (string)$itemElement->product_id,
    'whole_toppings' => [] ,
    'left_toppings' => [] 
  ];
  if ($itemElement->whole_toppings) {
    foreach ($itemElement->whole_toppings->topping as $toppingElement) {
     $item['whole_toppings'][] = (string)$toppingElement;
    }
  }
  if ($itemElement->left_toppings) {
    foreach ($itemElement->left_toppings->topping as $toppingElement) {
       $item['left_toppings'][] = (string)$toppingElement;
    }
  }
  $items[] = $item;
}

echo json_encode($items, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "product_id":"1",
    "whole_toppings":[
      "PEPPERONI"
    ],
    "left_toppings":[

    ]
  },
  {
    "product_id":"2",
    "whole_toppings":[
      "PEPPERONI",
      "MUSHROOMS"
    ],
    "left_toppings":[

    ]
  }
]
```

It is a little more work initially, but it provides you with a lot more control over the output. As you can see the JSON output has the a `whole_toppings` array for both products and a `left_toppings` array (but here is no tag for it in the XML).

To optimize it you can refactor logic into helper functions/methods.

```
function readToppingsList(
  SimpleXMLElement $itemElement, 
  string $listName, 
  string $itemName = 'topping'
): array {
  $toppings = [];
  if ($itemElement->{$listName}) {
    foreach ($itemElement->{$listName}->{$itemName} as $toppingElement) {
      $toppings[] = (string)$toppingElement;
    }
  }
  return $toppings;
}

$itemsElement = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);

$items = [];
foreach ($itemsElement->item as $itemElement) {
  $item = [
    'product_id' => (string)$itemElement->product_id,
    'whole_toppings' => readToppingsList($itemElement, 'whole_toppings'),
    'left_toppings' => readToppingsList($itemElement, 'left_toppings')
  ];
  $items[] = $item;
}

echo json_encode($items, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that helps a lot. I was wondering if i can have a ultimate automation solution for this situation, because the back-end provider doesn't provide me consist data source, which means any attribute that has sibling will result in the same problem, but it seems there is no way to automate it, i will just manually convert for every single one. Thanks for the helps

Comment: The problem is the difference between the formats - not the formats themselves. For an XML something like `<list><title/><item/><item/></list>` would be valid and consistent. Think about (X)HTML. It just does not translate to JSON as it makes an explicit difference between objects and arrays.